# How to turn an string into an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a little code for my programming class and we need to make a program that calculates the cost of building a desk. I need help changing my DrawerAmount to an integer, not a string!

```
def Drawers():
print("How many drawers are there?")
DrawerAmount = input(int)
print("Okay, I accept that the total amount of drawers is " + DrawerAmount + ".")
return DrawerAmount

def Desk():
    print("What type of wood is your desk?")
    DeskType = input()
    print("Alright, your desk is made of " + DeskType + ".")
    return DeskType

def Calculation(DrawerAmount, DeskType):
    if "m" in DeskType:
        FinalPrice = DrawerAmount * 30 + 180
    elif "o" in DeskType:
        FinalPrice = DrawerAmount * 30 + 140
    elif "p" in DeskType:
        FinalPrice = DrawerAmount * 30 + 100

def Total():
    print("The final price is " + FinalPrice )

DrawerAmount = Drawers()
DeskType = Desk()
Calculation(DrawerAmount, DeskType)
FinalPrice = Total()
```

Comment: int(DrawerAmount)

Comment: your indentation is off

Comment: Is your code even working, check `DrawerAmount = input(int)` ?

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct when posting Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: Don't start your variable names with capital letters.

Comment: @MooingRawr I am still given an error message, DrawerAmount doesn't want to add to the other integers for some reason. The error is: Can't convert 'int' objects to str implicitly

Comment: @khelwood: It is better to say not to use camel-case naming convention

Comment: @acornbuzz: That is because you are getting error at different place, i.e. `"The final price is " + FinalPrice`. Here use `str(FinalPrice)` instead. You can not concanate `int` to `str` similar to you can not add `str` to `int`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script4.py", line 27, in <module>
    Calculation(DrawerAmount, DeskType)
  File "script4.py", line 16, in Calculation
    FinalPrice = DrawerAmount * 30 + 180
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: @acornbuzz: It is mentioned in your error trace. Replace `DrawerAmount ` with `int(DrawerAmount) ` in the mentioned line

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri My new error messsage is : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script4.py", line 30, in <module>
    DrawerAmount = Drawers()
  File "script4.py", line 7, in Drawers
    print("Okay, I accept that the total amount of drawers is " + DrawerAmount + ".")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: @acornbuzz I already mentioned resolution of this issue in the previous comment. Check the one I made 16 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

> I need help changing my DrawerAmount to an integer, not a string!

Try this:

```
v = int(DrawerAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Drawers():
    draweramount = input("How many drawers are there?")
    print("Okay, I accept that the total amount of drawers is " + draweramount +     ".")
    return int(draweramount)

def Desk():
    desktype = input("What type of wood is your desk?")
    print("Alright, your desk is made of " + desktype + ".")
    return desktype

def Calculation(draweramount, desktype):
    if "m" in desktype:
        finalprice = draweramount * 30 + 180
    elif "o" in desktype:
        finalprice = draweramount * 30 + 140
    elif "p" in desktype:
        finalprice = draweramount * 30 + 100
    return finalprice

draweramount = Drawers()
desktype = Desk()
finalprice=Calculation(draweramount, desktype)
print("The final price is ",Calculation(draweramount,desktype) )
```

> You haven't specified the output in case the input is not "P" or "M" or "O". 
>   Have your functions in small letters and include **_** whenever its a combination of two or more words
>   eg. function_name()